# "No screens found" after apt-get upgrade with Intel video card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, xorg, intel

My Mythbuntu installation (based on Ubuntu 12.04), which has been running without issues for years, suddenly won't start X Windows after doing a simple `apt-get upgrade`.  Several packages were upgraded, but the relevant ones from `/var/log/dpkg.log` appear to be:

```
2013-06-01 11:13:19 upgrade lightdm 1.2.3-0ubuntu2 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.1
2013-06-01 11:13:49 upgrade liblightdm-gobject-1-0 1.2.3-0ubuntu2 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.1
2013-06-01 11:13:52 upgrade linux-generic 3.2.0.43.51 3.2.0.45.54
2013-06-01 11:13:52 upgrade linux-image-generic 3.2.0.43.51 3.2.0.45.54
2013-06-01 11:14:02 upgrade linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.43.51 3.2.0.45.54
```

The log from /var/log/Xorg.0.log is as follows:

```
[    35.853] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    35.853] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    35.853] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
[    35.853] Current Operating System: Linux mythtv 3.2.0-45-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:11:31 UTC 2013 i686
[    35.853] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-45-generic root=UUID=57cd8ecb-7fd4-4c9a-b0c3-cab934656a22 ro quiet splash vmalloc=256M vt.handoff=7
[    35.853] Build Date: 11 April 2013  01:04:30PM
[    35.853] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.13 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    35.853] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    35.853]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    35.853] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    35.854] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jun  5 08:52:03 2013
[    35.854] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.854] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    35.854] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    35.854] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    35.854] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    35.854] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    35.854] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.854] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.854] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    35.854]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.854] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
        built-ins
[    35.854] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    35.854] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    35.854] (II) Loader magic: 0xa075a0
[    35.854] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    35.854]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    35.854]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    35.854]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    35.854]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    35.855] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:2e42:1043:83cc rev 3, Mem @ 0xf9800000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/8
[    35.855] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:1) 8086:2e43:1043:83cc rev 3, Mem @ 0xf9f00000/1048576
[    35.855] (--) PCI: (0:1:1:0) 14f1:8800:7063:5500 rev 5, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216
[    35.855] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    35.855] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    35.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    35.856] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.856]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.856]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.856]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    35.856] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    35.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    35.856] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.856]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.856]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.856]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    35.856] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    35.856] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.856]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.856]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.856] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    35.856] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    35.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    35.856] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.856]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    35.856]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.856]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.856] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    35.856] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    35.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    35.857] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.857]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.857]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.857] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    35.857] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    35.857] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    35.857] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.857]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    35.857]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.857] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    35.857] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.857] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.857] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.857] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.857] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    35.857] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    35.857] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.857]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.19.0
[    35.857]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.857]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    35.857] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.857] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    35.857] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.857]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    35.857]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.857]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    35.857] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.858] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.858] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.858]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    35.858]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    35.858] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
        i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
        E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
        965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
        4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
        Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
        Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
        Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
        Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
        Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
        Ivybridge Server (GT2)
[    35.858] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    35.858] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    35.858] (--) using VT number 7

[    35.866] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    35.866] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    35.866] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    35.866] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    35.866] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.866] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    35.867] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.867]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    35.867]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    35.867] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    35.867] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    35.867] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[    35.867] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    35.867] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    35.867] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[    35.867] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
[    35.867] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    35.867] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    35.867] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    35.867] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    35.867] (II) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) B43
[    35.867] (--) intel(0): Chipset: "B43"
[    35.867] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    35.867] (II) Unloading intel
[    35.867] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    35.867] 
Fatal server error:
[    35.867] no screens found
[    35.867] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    35.867] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    35.867] 
[    35.879]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[    35.879] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The PC contains an integrated Intel video card (Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)) and an HD-5500 HDTV TV tuner card (Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder (rev 05)).

There is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

So far, I've tried the following:

1. Downgrading to an older Linux kernel:

   ```
   apt-get install linux-generic=3.2.0.45.54
   ```
2. Downgrading `lightdm`:

   ```
   apt-get install lightdm=1.2.1-0ubuntu1
   ```
3. Running `X -configure` and restarting (I deleted the generated `xorg.conf` after it didn't work)

So far, I seem to get the same error no matter what I do.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I was able to fix it by switching to the experimental xorg-edgers video card drivers PPA, and installing unity-2d, as follows:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

Use this at [your own risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo), please understand that PPAs can break your system.  Learn more about the [xorg-edgers PPA here](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

Comment: If you are visiting this page in 2023, you will get a 404 for this ppa. Refer this page for installing unity https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-install-ubuntu-unity-ppa/2090

Answer (score 0):

I think Intel graphic drivers are installed during OS installation.

Your problem in likely that you need the libraries for texture compression installed- they are not installed by default due to copyright issues.  They are needed for nearly all 3D games.  With the libraries missing, I suspect that the game thinks the drivers are not there because the game is looking for S3TC support. Without the libraries, the card will not advertise S3TC support hence the game will crash.

Running the following will install the libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

or just search for [libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0) [image: Install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0] in the Software Center.

This fix has no risks at all... tested by me several times.
I hope it will help you....
...feel free to comment your queries...

Comment: Thanks Anky, however I already have/had that package installed, so I don't think that's the issue.